Show that $1^T(tI-B)^{-1}\mathbb{1}=0$ when $B$ is the adjacency matrix of a regular graph
I want to show that $1^T(tI-B)^{-1}\mathbb{1}=0$ when $B$ is the adjacency matrix of a regular graph on $2m$ vertices, where $1$ denotes the all ones vector. This is part of a bigger problem and it's the last step I need to finish. I don't know how to start, because inverting the matrix $tI-B$ already seems very complicated. Could someone help me?

I assume you are working over $\mathbb R$.  You should be able to infer that if $(tI-B)^{-1}$ exists, then $\mathbf 1$ is an eigenvector so $\mathbf 1^T(tI-B)^{-1}\mathbf{1} \neq 0$

@user8675309 why is $1$ an eigenvector?

take a look under "properties" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph to see $\mathbf 1$ is an eigenvector of $B$ which implies it is an eigenvector of $(tI-B)$

@user8675309 I know why $1$ is an eigenvector of $B$, but what I don't see is why is it an eigenvector of $(tI-B)^{-1}$. Perhaps this is something about linear algebra that I have forgotten...

prove to yourself if $v$ is an eigenvector of both $A$ and $B$, then it is an eigenvector of $C=A+B$.  Then prove if $Cv = \lambda v$ then $C^{-1}$, supposing it exists, satisfies $C^{-1}v = \lambda^{-1}v$

What is $t$, please. Keep in mind this question/answer isn't only for you but also for whomever may look at this too. And yes you also need to put context too.

Summing up the $i$th row of $B$ means counting the number of neighbors of the node $i$ in the graph. For a $d$-regular graph, this will be $d$ (constant across nodes). That is, $B\mathbf{1}=d\mathbf{1}$. Further, you have that $\left(I-B/t\right)^{-1}= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} B^{i}/t^{i}$, whenever the spectral radius of $B/t$ is smaller than $1$, i.e., $\rho(B/t)<1$. This is equivalent to $\left|d/t\right|<1$ or $d<|t|$, as the eigenvalue $d$ happens to be also the spectral radius of $B$. Under the assumption $0\neq d<|t|$, you have
$$\left(I-\frac{B}{t}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{1}=\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{B^{i}}{t^{i}}\right)\mathbf{1}= \left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{d^i}{t^i}\right)\mathbf{1}=\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{d}{t}}\right)\mathbf{1}.$$
Therefore, if $0\neq d<|t|$, then
$$\mathbf{1}^{\top}\left(tI-B\right)^{-1}\mathbf{1}=\left(1/t\right)\mathbf{1}^{\top}\left(I-\frac{B}{t}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{1}=\frac{N}{t-d}\neq 0,$$
where $N=2m$ is the number of nodes in the graph.

Why can you substitute $B^i$ for $d^i$ in the sum? I know they are not the same (one is a matrix and the other is an integer), so I guess you are applying some property that I am not seeing right now

$B\mathbf{1}=d\mathbf{1} \Rightarrow B^2\mathbf{1}=B B \mathbf{1}=d B\mathbf{1}=d^2\mathbf{1}$. Via induction, $B^i\mathbf{1}=d^i\mathbf{1}$.

Let $B$ be the adjacency matrix of a regular graph. If $(tI-B)$ is invertible then ${\bf{1}}^{\top}(tI-B)^{-1}{\bf{1}}$ must be nonzero.
First, it is straightforward to check that ${\bf{1}}$ is an eigenvector of $tI$, $B$, and thus $(tI-B)$, and if $(tI-B)$ is invertible, then ${\bf{1}}$ is also an eigenvector $(tI-B)^{-1}$, with nonzero eigenvalue. [Indeed, as $B$ is the adjacency matrix of a regular graph, then letting $d$ be the nonnegative integer such that $d$-regular, it follows that ${\bf{1}}$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $d$ [and an eigenvector of $tI$ with eigenvalue $t$], and thus is an eigenvalue of $(tI-B)$ with eigenvalue $t-d$. Assuming $tI-B$ is invertible [and thus, that $t-d$ is nonzero] then:
$$(tI-B)^{-1}(tI-B){\bf{1}} \ = \ {\bf{1}}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{t-d}(t-d){\bf{1}} \ = \ (tI-B)^{-1}((t-d){\bf{1}}),$$ with $t-d$ nonzero. And so this gives $(t-d){\bf{1}}$ is indeed an eigenvector of $(tI-B)^{-1}$, and thus ${\bf{1}}$ is indeed an eigenvector of $(tI-B)^{-1}$ also, with corresponding eigenvalue $\frac{1}{t-d}$, which is nonzero.]
From this the fact  that ${\bf{1}}^{\top}(tI-B)^{-1}{\bf{1}}$ must be nonzero [given the existence of $(tI-B)^{-1}$ in the first place], follows immediately. In fact, ${\bf{1}}^{\top}(tI-B)^{-1}{\bf{1}} = \frac{{\bf{1}}^{\top}{\bf{1}}}{t-d}$ $=\frac{n}{t-d}$, where $n$ is the number of vertices in the graph that $B$ us the adjacency matrix of.
